# How to get the 'file://' url for a file from bash CLI

Tags: mac-osx, bash

Is there a simple utility that will print a file's URL to the console? An example (where url is said utility), given a file `index.html` in `/var/www/index.html`:

```
user@server$ url index.html
file:///var/www/index.html
user@server$
```

If it makes a difference, I'm on Mac OS X, Mountain Lion.

Comment: Apologies... the question is more appropriate for superuser.com... where it turns out it's already answered:

http://superuser.com/questions/205127/how-to-retrieve-the-absolute-path-of-an-arbitrary-file-from-the-os-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 #!/bin/sh
 #/usr/local/bin/url
 echo file://`readlink -f $1`
```

The `readlink` command will traverse the path up to find whatever the full path to any specified file is. Put in a script, this is passing whatever argument you make to readlink and prepending it with "file://"

Comment: the `readlink` solution also happens to be relatively portable and shell-independent.

Comment: Unfortunately, although this works fine on e.g. Ubuntu, this will not actually work on Mac OS X 10.8 (or 10.6 for that matter), where `readlink` is just an alternative, simplified invocation of `stat`. Rather, it results in the following error:

`readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]`

Comment: See this [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html).

Comment: If you install the GNU tool `greadlink` e.g. using a package manager like [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and then change the suggested shell script appropriately, that will work. However, this solution still doesn't take care of percent encoding for the URL, which, since spaces are common in OS X file and folder names, would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to tackle this. From the command line you would do:

```
cd / 
find .|grep index.html|sed 's&./&file:///&1'
```

You will need to do this from a privileged account. If the file name changes you can script the above command to expand your searches fairly easily. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

do you need this?

```
alias url="echo  file://$(pwd)$1"
```

Comment: We generally prefer answers that have a little bit more detail than this (the "why", not just "do you need [insert command here]").  Please consider adding some detail to your answer.  Thanks.